# Semantic UI Modal dialog not closing properly

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI (http://semantic-ui.com/) as the front end CSS library and also AngularJS. In my application, I used modals to manage data input and views. There's a problem. I am opening and closing modals using following commands.

```
$('#addNewEpisodeModal').modal('show');
$('#addNewEpisodeModal').modal('hide');
```

But sometimes when I close the modal, it's not closing properly. Modal dialog closing, but there's a black dimmer (background) not closing. And I will show you how it's working. This is my modal when I open it.

[image]

And this is the view when I close that modal. The dimmed background is not closing. Can anyone tell me what's the problem here ?

[image]

I have to refresh the page in order to make it working again. What's the reason for this ?

Comment: can you please put it in snippet or fiddle?

Comment: @SagarKodte Actually it's a huge application with using lot of server side code. :( Hard to make a fiddle :(

Comment: so can u able to provide link??

Comment: @SagarKodte Hey, There are multiple modals in a same view. Think i open a modal and from that modal, i open another new modal. So the first modal have to closed. Can you tell me a proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered that problem once and my solution was to hide the dimmer manually together with the modal:

```
$('#addNewEpisodeModal').modal('hide').modal('hide dimmer');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so without more clarification from you (e.g. example code), this is nothing more than a guess on my part. However, here are my thoughts:

Semantic UI manipulates your `.modal` element by extracting it from wherever you had it, wrapping it in a `.modals` element, and inserting that element into the body of your page. This happens when `.modal('show')` is first called, and not before.

Once your modal is hidden, the `.modals` element receives a new class of `hidden`, which will hide the black overlay. My assumption is that you have overwritten this .hidden class, or the styles that it gives to the element. I would try looking at the CSS in Chrome's developer tools, and seeing if this is the case.

Comment: There are multiple modals in a same page. So can you please tell me a proper way to open and close modals ? I mean i want to open a modal and in that modal, i want to open another one.. So the first modal have to close

Comment: There is [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#multiple-modals) for this.